# deploy artifacts to remote VM from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to automate deployment proceeses using Jenkins. I am trying to deploy some config files and some EAR files  to  remote VM. Normally I would  open a Remote Desktop connection and deploy manually.

Is there a way FROM JENKINS through scripting or plugin where I can deploy files to a remote VM?

Comment: That depends on the target OS and target Application Server/Container, I guess. You can execute shell commands in your jenkins build, so anything you can script in bash (for example) you can do that. We have a simple bash script that deploys our ears remotely using glassfish's asadmin command. Alternatively you can copy them by ssh/scp.

Comment: Target OS is Windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/dblock/remoteinstall) framework which automates the management and deployment of files on remote VM's running in a VMWare environment.

Just install RI on your Jenkins server and add batch steps to execute the RI executable with a XML configuration that should do what you want.